# How center a angularjs material card (md-card) vertically and horizontally? (Angular 1.x)

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I've a problem I'm sure would had a simple solution that I don't find. I'm building a simple login page where I've a angular material card (md-card) and nothing more. Inside it I've the normal fields in this cases.

But the problem appear when I try to center this card vertically and horizontally, it's seem imposible. I've seen the [doc](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment) about this and this would be so simple as use 
`layout="row" layout-align="center center"`but obviusly don't work for me. I searched several examples in codepen and plunker but nobody do this with md-card.

Somebody have a simple example to how center only a md-card in a view?

Comment: please change in the title too, for google search results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a simple way to do this:

```
<div layout-fill layout="column" layout-align="center none">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center none">

        <md-card>

            <md-card-title>
                <md-card-title-text>
                    <span class="md-headline">Card title</span>
                </md-card-title-text>
            </md-card-title>

            <md-card-content>
                Card content
            </md-card-content>

        </md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you have to import to get access to `layout-fill`?

Comment: This answer is more complete: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212473/how-to-center-align-card-in-angular-material-4?rq=1

Comment: Thanks for the link @Pier

Answer (score 9):

You can try by setting dimensions of the element, and then adding:

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

It should center this horizontally.

Comment: Thanks but this don't work for me. I don't understand why this code :


`<div  layout="column" layout-align="center none"> Sample </div> `

don't work and I don't see "Sample" center vertically.

Comment: this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zBQZLW?editors=1010#0)

- Column centered

  - Row centered, flex="50"

    - Card, flex="50"

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp" layout-fill layout="column" style="background:green" layout-align="center">
    <div flex="50" layout="row" layout-align="center">
      <md-card flex="50"></md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just find a similar way to do this, but without `flex="50"`. Thanks!

Comment: @JuanAntonio Glad to be of help. I just added `flex=50` for extra info.