# How to center align card in angular material 4?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have created a sample angular 4 application with angular material.
I'm trying to center the card in the view.
But its not working.Below is the code

**app.component.html**

```
<!--The content below is only a placeholder and can be replaced.-->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div  ng-cloak=""  layout-fill layout="column" style="background:green" layout-align="center">
    <div flex="50" layout="row" layout-align="center">
      <md-card flex="50"></md-card>
    </div>
</div>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MdCardModule,MdInputModule } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 21):

Add a class to the `md-card` something like this:

```
.center{
  width: 75%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.main-div{
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="main-div">
  <md-card class="z-depth center" flex="50" >Simple card</md-card>
</div>
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/29wR6WqS0L9Dkv4BKF7Y?p=preview)

Comment: center both horizontally and vertically